# Internet Explorer + Windows8 Touchscreen issues

Tags: internet-explorer, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, windows-8, touchscreen

We are experiencing an issue related to **Google Maps API V3**. The issue is that while we drag the Marker the map also starts dragging.

We are experiencing this **issue ONLY on Touch Screens in Windows 8 Environment + Internet Explorer**, its fine on NORMAL screens / Mobile Screens - IPaid/ other browsers (Safari and FireFox).

We used below solution, but it throws error (`eval javascript error`) in **Internet Explorer9 and 10**:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function(){
    mapObject.setOptions({ draggable: false });
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(){
    mapObject.setOptions({ draggable: true });
});
```

[Sample code is here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mppw4/3/).

We have also reported this issue here:
[gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5292&thanks=5292&ts=1366679575)

**EDIT:**

We have a posted a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168369/is-googlemaps-api-v3-supports-touch-event) here also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Some success At Last** (the map still move a bit but can be ignored at the moment)!

**Declared two variables:**

```
var isAnyMarkerIsInDraggingState = false;// if a marker is in drag state this value will be TRUE otherwise FALSE
var mapCenterPositionAtTheTimeWhenMarkerWasDragged;// Map Center Position
```

**When Marker is dragged:**

```
   google.maps.event.addListener(objMarker, 'dragstart', function () {
        // Store map center position when a marker is dragged
        mapCenterPositionAtTheTimeWhenMarkerWasDragged = mapObject.getCenter();
        isAnyMarkerIsInDraggingState = true;
    });
```

**When Marker is dropped (drag ends):**

```
google.maps.event.addListener(objMarker, 'dragend', function () {
    // Make Map draggable
    // Set isAnyMarkerIsInDraggingState = false. Because no marker is in drag state
    mapObject.setOptions({ draggable: true });
    isAnyMarkerIsInDraggingState = false;
});
```

**When the Map Drag starts:**

```
google.maps.event.addListener(mapObject, 'dragstart', function () {
    // isAnyMarkerIsInDraggingState = true: means the user is dragging a marker.
    // If the user is dragging the Marker then don't allow the Map to be Dragged
    if (isAnyMarkerIsInDraggingState) {
        mapObject.setOptions({ draggable: false });
    }
});
```

**When Map is in dragging state:**

```
google.maps.event.addListener(mapObject, 'drag', function () {
    // isAnyMarkerIsInDraggingState = true: means the user is dragging a marker.
    // If the user is dragging the Marker then don't allow the Map to be Dragged and set its CenterPosition
    // to mapCenterPositionAtTheTimeWhenMarkerWasDragged

    if (isAnyMarkerIsInDraggingState) {
        mapObject.setCenter(mapCenterPositionAtTheTimeWhenMarkerWasDragged);
    }
});
```

[Complete sample code is here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mppw4/5/).