# Gmaps listeners click and rightclick do not work on smartphone

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Gmaps v3 on a website that performs some functions on the map's click and rightclick events.
In the web browser on the computer everything works without problems.
Already if I use the browser (whatever it is) from a smartphone these listeners do not work, how can I intercept the click and rightclick events in a browser used in the smartphone?

```
 map.addListener('rightclick', function(event) {
  var clicked = {lat: event.latLng.lat(), lng: event.latLng.lng()}; 
  infoWindowOptionsMapa.setPosition(clicked);      
  infoWindowOptionsMapa.open(map);
  infoWindows.push(infoWindowOptionsMapa);      
  sessionStorage.removeItem('clicked');
  sessionStorage.setItem('clicked',JSON.stringify(clicked));     
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click',function(e) {
    closeAllInfoWindows();        
    checkClass();  
});
```

I researched a bit more and tested the code below, but Chrome does not work.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'mousedown',function(e) {
  var clicked = {lat: e.latLng.lat(), lng: e.latLng.lng()}; 
  alert(clicked);
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events AND

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168369/does-google-maps-api-v3-support-touch-event

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because on mobile there is no mouse so you can not use click (or rightclick) event.

You should use touch event. It's described well [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events).

You should use library like [jQuery UI Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com), but its meant only for jQuery UI.

You would have to use some workaround to get it to work with Gmaps.